# Smallest possible Scratch 3.0 project file (SB3)

Tags: code-golf, compression, json

The objective is to make the smallest SB3 file that can simply be imported into Scratch 3.0 without a "The project file that was selected failed to load" error. Any means can be used, like editing the JSON or better compression. Here's where I am with project.json, the only file inside mine:

```
{"targets":[{"isStage":true,"name":"Stage","variables":{},"lists":{},"broadcasts":{},"blocks":{},"comments":{},"costumes":[{"assetId":"00000000000000000000000000000000","name":"","md5ext":"00000000000000000000000000000000.svg","dataFormat":"svg"}],"sounds":[]}],"meta":{"semver":"3.0.0","vm":"0.0.0"}}
```

Comment: I retagged it to [tag:code-golf], which is essentially "smallest file [in bytes] that works".

Comment: Helpful link: https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Scratch_File_Format

Answer (score 2):

## 303 bytes

I think this is the lowest possible score. I managed to remove some more stuff from `project.json` and used the best compression 7-zip could offer me. File is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OG11X6RIQPhHM3Lwl5iBddG-kPUm9VYN/view?usp=sharing).

project.json

```
{"targets":[{"isStage":true,"name":"Stage","variables":{},"blocks":{},"costumes":[{"assetId":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","name":"","md5ext":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.svg","dataFormat":"svg"}],"sounds":[]}],"meta":{"semver":"3.0.0","vm":"0.1.0"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## <s>263</s> 257 bytes

The MD5 uses 0s instead of As, `semver` and `vm`'s locations are swapped, `vm`'s `0.0.0`, `project.json`'s creation, modification and access times are 01/01/2000 00:00:00 with the N (none) attribute (Attribute Changer 10 used) and FileOptimizer's used to optimize the SB3's compression.

```
{"targets":[{"isStage":true,"name":"Stage","variables":{},"blocks":{},"costumes":[{"assetId":"00000000000000000000000000000000","name":"","md5ext":"00000000000000000000000000000000.svg","dataFormat":"svg"}],"sounds":[]}],"meta":{"vm":"0.0.0","semver":"3.0.0"}}
```


I've done some more swapping, used the A (archive) attribute and changed all the numbers to 3, even the date and time (03/03/3333 03:33:33). Oddly, the year 2108 problem occurs after optimization.

```
{"targets":[{"costumes":[{"assetId":"33333333333333333333333333333333","md5ext":"33333333333333333333333333333333.svg","dataFormat":"svg","name":""}],"name":"Stage","isStage":true}],"blocks":{},"sounds":[],"variables":{},"meta":{"semver":"3.3.3","vm":"3.3.3"}}
```